# Date from now plus 4 days with a cut off time of 3pm

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

i have a script that works, however i am looking to add a cut off time

```
function displaydate_tomorrow(){
    return date('l jS F', strtotime('+4 weekday'));
}
add_shortcode('tomorrow', 'displaydate_tomorrow');
```

I need to add in a 3pm cut off time so that when it turns 3pm it goes to the next day, not sure how to add that into this piece...

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
function displaydate_tomorrow(){
    $date = new DateTime('now');
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P4D'));
    if ($date->format('H') >= '15') {
        $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }

    return $date->format('l jS F');
}
add_shortcode('tomorrow', 'displaydate_tomorrow');
```